# Independent radiobuttons for each row read from server

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently trying to generate independent radio buttons for each row read from my server. They are supposed to symbolize ON and OFF Switches. My current issue is that I manage to generate buttons for each row but these are not independent. I can only turn one off or on at a time.

I know that radio buttons become truly "independent" when the name of each is different. But I can't seem to figure out a way to create a new name for each row generated.

Currently my code looks like this

```
    res = $db->query($query);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM device_status
                            WHERE device = ($row->id)";
                  $status = $db->query($query);
                  $device_status = $status->fetch_object();
              $content .= <<<END
            <tr>
                <td>{$row->devices}</td>
                <td>{$row->description}</td>
                <td>{$row->room}</td>
                <td><input type='radio' name='radiobutton' id='myCheck'></td>
                <td><input type='radio' name='radiobutton' id='myCheck' checked='checked'></td>
                <!-- <td>{$device_status->status}</td> -->
                <td><a href="delete-device.php?id=$row->id">Delete</a>
                <a href="edit-device.php?id=$row->id">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
END;
                        }
                    }
    echo $content;
```

I've been trying different methods such as using `<td><input type='radio' name='$row->id' id='myCheck'></td>`

But have not gotten it to work. Any help on how to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So, if the name of each radio-button was created with a string and a counter, they'd all all uniques name, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the unique names for all the checkboxes generated you can have them by just incrementing `$i` for each row.

```
res = $db->query($query);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
                  $i = 0;
                while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM device_status
                            WHERE device = ($row->id)";
                  $status = $db->query($query);
                  $device_status = $status->fetch_object();
              $content .= <<<END
            <tr>
                <td>{$row->devices}</td>
                <td>{$row->description}</td>
                <td>{$row->room}</td>
                <td><input type='radio' name='radiobutton<?php echo $i?>' id='myCheck'></td>
                <td><input type='radio' name='radiobutton<?php echo $i?>' id='myCheck' checked='checked'></td>
                <!-- <td>{$device_status->status}</td> -->
                <td><a href="delete-device.php?id=$row->id">Delete</a>
                <a href="edit-device.php?id=$row->id">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            END;
            $i++;
                        }

                    }
    echo $content;
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution, thank you very much! This solved my issue straight away.

Comment: i'm glad i could help:)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the name of the radio button, you could use a "php random number generator", each row you asign a new random number to your radio button name:

```
<?php $x = rand(5, 100000); ?> <input type='radio' name='<?php echo $x; ?>' id='myCheck'>
```

Comment: You could create an array and store a certain amount of random numbers in it, if your newly generated number is already in that array don't use that number and generate a new one. It might be a little extra work, but will pay out in the end.

Comment: but it is not an efficient method.